# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when deploying my Maven project (EAR) in WildFly 11

Tags: hibernate, maven, jboss, wildfly, ear

I outsourced my project to a freelancer and he developed a Maven project for me and now I want to deploy it to the server but I am facing a few errors.

I tried to deploy the chalk-salt.ear file in JBoss-EAP-6.4, JBoss-as-7.1, wildfly-8.2-final and wildfly-11.0-final. I am getting dependency errors in each version of JBoss and wildfly that I have used for deployment.

I read a lot and solved the dependencies for wildfly-11.0-final, but now I am getting a single error class not found error that I am unable to understand.

I added modules of mysql, slf4j, jcl-over-slf4j and solved the issues of these module dependencies.

I have successfully deployed the ear file using the Management Console:

Steps for Deployment:

1. Go to Deployment and click on Add
2. Browse the `chalk-salt.ear` file and give **Name:** `chalk-salt.ear` and **Run Time Name:** `chalk-salt.ear`
3. After finishing I got an error:

   ```
    Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./chalk-salt-api" => "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/method/MethodConstraintViolationException Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/method/MethodConstraintViolationException Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodConstraintViolationException from [Module \"deployment.chalk-salt.ear.chalk-salt-api-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
   ```

After trying 4-5 times and changing hibernate validation module. It is successfully deployed from the management panel. But I am unable to access it from URL. Then I tried to deploy manually.

- I started `wildfly-11.0-final`
- Copy paste the `chalk-salt.ear` file into deployment folder. Command Terminal shows same error on each try.

I read the error and searched for it so I came to know that Project is built on Hibernate Validator 4.2 and Wildfly is using Hibernate 5 Library. I tried to add Hibernate Validator 4.2 Modules in my WildFly but after that WildFly is unable to start.

Can anyone help me to deploy and access my project using the URL. And how can I add Hibernate 4.2 in WildFly?

Comment: My Developer deployed it on JBoss-eap-6.4 on his system. I tried with Jboss-eap-6.4 but I am unable to start the server. I tried changing the JDK version. But No Success. Please Help

Comment: Please provide your pom.xml for the project. You may be missing dependencies.

Comment: Do you have a jboss-deployment-structure.xml? (If yes, please provide it) If the hibernate dependencies are in the ear, then you can exclude the hibernate main slot in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml